# Writing lambda expression for Dictionary<string,string> member

Tags: c#, lambda

i want to achieve this simple lambda with expressions.

```
x => x.myDictionary["key"] == "value"
```

This is I have done so far.

```
 var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
 var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "myDictionary");
 var expressionCall = Expression.Call(memberExpression, typeof(IDictionary<string, string>).GetMethod("get_Item"), Expression.Constant("key"));

 var eq1 = Expression.Equal(expressionCall, Expression.Constant("value"));

 var lambda = Expression.Lambda(eq1, parameterExpression);

 q.Where(lambda);
```

But the filter is not working. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `IEnumerable.Where` expects a `Func<...>` and `IQueryable.Where` expects an `Expression<Func<...>>` but `Expression.Lambda` returns an `LambdaExpression` object which is not an `Expression<Func...>>`.

Comment: Are you intending to generate a `Func<...>` or an `Expression<Func<...>>`? (i..e do you want to use it with Linq-to-Objects or Linq-to-Entities?)

Comment: @Dai sorry for the late response. `q` is a `IQueryable<T>`. I want to add new filters to `q` with an extension method. And it turned out that the extension method was not working. If I apply this logic directly It works.